# Website’s security certificate message on IE

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, deployment, https

I have deployed my asp.net mvc web on IIS and I add a valid security certificate for my asp.net mvc web application. But currently when the users access the application they will always receive the following message;-
[image]
While when accessing the system using Firefox or Chrome no message will be displayed. So can anyone advice what is causing this message to appear on IE ?
Thanks

Comment: Is the IE vs. Chrome/Firefox distinction just what _you_ see, or have users reported this consistent difference too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid and trusted certificates are two different things.

**1)** Judging by IE's message...

> The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.

..., it looks like your site is using a self-signed certificate or other certificate that is valid (e.g. not expired) but not trusted - i.e. verifiable by a chain of trust to a trusted certificate authority (CA).

A host or domain certificate issued (and therefore verifiable) by a (CA trusted by a) trusted CA will address this 1st issue.

**2)** Also, judging by IE's subsequent message...

> The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.

..., your site is using a host certificate issued for a different hostname (e.g. `yourserver` - recorded in its `CN`, or common name) than the one to which you sent your request (e.g. `www`).

A host certificate issued for the same hostname (e.g. with `CN=www.yourdomain.com`) to which requests are sent (i.e. `www.yourdomain.com`) will address this 2nd issue.  A domain certificate issued for the same domain (e.g. with `CN=yourdomain.com`) to which requests are sent will also address it.

**3)** *However*, regarding *IE behaving differently* than Chrome and Firefox, are you sure that you did not previously add an exception for the site & certificate in Firefox or Chrome?  In my experience, all the browsers in question warn about untrusted certificates (albeit a bit differently).

Here are examples of warnings in IE, Chrome, and Firefox for a site that is using an untrusted (self-signed) certificate:

[image: Untrusted Certificate Warning in IE]

[image: Untrusted Certificate Warning in Chrome]

[image: Untrusted Certificate Warning in Firefox]